# I have stomach ache vs I have 'a' stomach ache

Tags: grammar, articles

I'm confused about this particular sentence, and other ones using ache,I know that 'I have a headache' is correct and works, but it sounds a little weird to me if someone says 'I have a stomachache/a toothache/a backache/an earache'. I feel that with the exception of headache, these should all be uncountable, does anyone agree with me or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Nothing to back it up, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but all your examples with articles sound perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Why would a headache be any different from these other aches?

Comment: Barking. Wrong. Tree. All use the indefinite article.

Comment: Sorry, but you're incorrect. All of those aches sound strange (read: wrong) without the article. Perhaps you're conflating the verb with the noun? "My stomach aches" naturally doesn't use an article. [Interesting historical note: Victorian novels often have their heroines suffering from ***the*** headache, rather than ***a*** headache. Dunno the reasoning behind that.]

Comment: Aches and pains and diseases are all over the map. _The flu, the grippe, the heaves, the galloping never-get-overs,_ but _a/an headache/earache, a pain in the neck/butt/lower colon_, but also _pneumonia, asthma, heart/kidney/lung disease_ (but _a disease of the heart/kidney/lung_). Don't expect it to make sense; **English article use is almost entirely idiomatic. You have to learn the idioms**. Sorry about that. That's to make up for not having inflectional paradigms like Russian or Finnish.

Comment: @Martha: You might find that Victorian ladies had _the_ headache because it was not just a complaint but rather a complete behavioural suite with firmly established causes, permissions and regimens.  So in a way there was only the one headache to go round.

Comment: In British English, all but headache are mass nouns: see http://www.englishgrammar.org/countable-uncountable-nouns-special-cases/

Answer (score 0):

While it is common for one to see the words, "headache", "stomachache" etc., spelled as one word, they are actually closed compound words.

Take out the noun adjunct (e.g., head, stomach) and say the sentence again without the indefinite article:

"I have ache."

So ache is in fact a count noun, with a noun adjunct modifier attached. Hence the indefinite article.

Hope this helps?

Comment: -1 *Ache* may be a count noun, but *headache*, *toothache* and *stomachache* can be mass nouns, [at least in British English and purportedly in American English](http://www.englishgrammar.org/countable-uncountable-nouns-special-cases/) too.